# Has this Peculiar Property of Unit Circles Already been Noticed?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-equations

Yesterday I needed to do some calculations with circles and "ventured" to calculate the arc length via the $\int{\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2}}$ formula and was baffled to see that in the case of unit half-circles that amounts to $\ ds := \sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} = \frac{1}{f(x)}$

Stuffing that differential equation in WA yields the four solutions $f(x) = \pm\sqrt{-2 c_1 x - c_1^2 - x^2 + 1}\ $and $f(x) = \pm\sqrt{2 c_1 x - c_1^2 - x^2 + 1}\ $

> **Questions:**
>
> - has that special property been noted before?
> - are there other functions, whose arclength differential satisfies $\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} = g\left(f(x)\right)$, when $g()$ is an ordinary, explicit function?

Comment: Are you asking whether is has ever been noted before that $\sqrt{1+(\tan(\theta))^2}$ equals $\sec(\theta)$?

Comment: @JasonStarr no, Iam aware, that the arclength differential can often be expressed by simple functions; what I am looking for, are arclength differentials, that are explicit functions, where the variable has been replaced by the original function and $sec(\theta)$ doesn't qualify as $g(tan(\theta))$, or do I miss something?

Comment: Let me clarify my comment.  The answer to your first question, "has that special property been noted before" is: yes, for circles this is one of the elementary identities of trigonometry equivalent to the identity $\sqrt{1+(\tan(\theta))^2} = \sec(\theta)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr write down an explicit function $g(x)$ with some text editor and then replace '$x$' with '$f(\theta)$'; if you then have $\sqrt{1+(f'(\theta))^2} = g(\theta)$, then that specific $f(\theta)$ is an example of what i am looking for.

Comment: Okay, the second example that we teach in freshman calculus is the "astroid".  Here $f(x)$ equals $(1-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$, and $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$ equals $g(f(x))$ where $g(\theta)$ equals $-(1-\theta^{2/3})^{-1/2}$.  It is much simpler to write this parametrically as $x(t) = (\cos(t))^3$, $y(t) = (\sin(t))^3$, $ds/dt = 3\sin(t)\cos(t)$.

Comment: My favorite example of a plane curve whose arclength is explicitly computable is the (rational) cubic $9y^2-x(x-3)^2=0$.  When one parametrizes it by $(x,y) = (t^2,\,t^3/3{-}t)$, one has $\mathrm{d}s = (t^2+1)\,\mathrm{d}t$, so $s_1-s_0 = (t_1-t_0)((t_1-t_0)^2+3)/3$, which can be expressed rationally in terms of $(x_1,y_1)$  and $(x_0,y_0)$, since $t_i = 3y_i/(x_i-3)$ (as long as $x_i\not=3$).

Comment: @RobertBryant there is a whole family of curves called Pythagorean Hodograph curves that share that property, the most prominent being the Tschirnhausen cubic. That is the reason why I asked for explicit functions and why I was surprised to see the simple relation between arclength differential and function for an explicit function.

Comment: @ManfredWeis:  I've seen this term "Pythagorean Hodograph curve" before, but I wonder whether people know how old this fact is (which can be found in Darboux, but was known earlier):  If arc length $s$ is an algebraic function on an algebraic curve $P(x,y)=0$ (other than a line), then there is an algebraic curve $G(u,v)=0$ such that $$x = (1-u^2)\,v''+2u\,v'-2v,\quad y=2u\,v''-2v',\quad s = (1+u^2)\,v''-2u\,v'+2v,$$ where $v' = dv/du$ and $v''=d^2v/du^2$.  Are 'Pythagorean hodograph curves' something beyond this?

Comment: @RobertBryant the thing about PH curves is to be able to easily construct them by adapting the identity $(1-n^2)^2+(2n)^2=(1+n^2)^2$ to the derivative of parametric functions, thus generating parametric polynomial curves with rational length function. That is very beneficial for applied mathematics related to free form curves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are asking whether there are functions $f$ such that $(f')^2=h(f)$. (I denote $h=g^2-1$). The answer is yes: these functions are solutions of the differential equation
$f'=\sqrt{h(f)}$. The general solution of this equation is: $$\int\frac{df}{\sqrt{h(f)}}=x+c.$$
In your case, $h$ is a quadratic rational function. Taking other quadratic functions you obtain various integrals which can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. If $h$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$, the integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions but it
is an elliptic integral. It is actually one of the earliest problems where an elliptic integral was encountered: the arc length of ellipse and Bernoulli lemniscate.

See, for example, [MR1469740](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1469740) Prasolov, Viktor; Solovyev, Yuri, Elliptic functions and elliptic integrals. Translated from the Russian manuscript by D. Leites. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1997.

Comment: In particular, for the astroid, $h(f)$ equals $(1-f^{2/3})^{-1}-1=f^{2/3}/(1-f^{2/3}).$ I had a superfluous minus sign in my comment above.  In this case $df/\sqrt{h(f)}$ equals $f^{-1/3}\sqrt{1-f^{2/3}}df$.  Substituting $e=1-f^{2/3}$, $de = -(2/3)f^{-1/3}df$, the differential is $-(3/2)e^{1/2}de = d(-e^{3/2})$.  So the astroid is one more case where the integral above can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I believe that all cases when $h$ is an algebraic function have been in principle classified: J. Davenport,  On the integration of algebraic functions.  Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1981.

Comment: thank you all for the nice feedback; maybe those examples are useful for class rooms..

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the fact that the circle has constant curvature. Indeed the curvature of a curve obtained plotting  $ y=f(x) $ is  $\mathcal{C}_{f}(x)=f''(x)(1+(f'(x))^{2})^{-3/2} $, which comes from the definition of the curvature as the derivative of the angle in function of the distance $d\alpha/ds$. Note that's there no other function in $C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ than the constant function $f:x\mapsto 0$ such that for all $x$ one has $\mathcal{C}_{f}(x)=f(x)$ (I asked the question some years ago here or on MSE).

Comment: Do you mean this question: [Techniques to solve a non linear differential equation related to curvature](https://mathoverflow.net/q/239993)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for digging it out.

Comment: I do not see a connection: in your question it is important that the function is defined on the whole real line (ODE always have some solutions, locally).